# Appending a Pandas .read_excel dataframe to a new dataframe

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to read several XLS files into a Panda's dataframe.  They appear to read in correctly - but when I trying and display(df), df.info() or df.head() the dataframe is empty.

All data is in subfolder named `data1`.  xls sheets are named `a.xls` and `b.xls`.

The data sets are as follows:

a.xls

```
Account Description Final   Adjustment  Adj Final
324     Testing1    2342             0   2342
232     Essential   5678             0   5678
35      Options     2345             0   2345
634     Working       45          5675   5720
23      Time       45774             0  45774
52      Styling       67             0     67
```

b.xls

```
Account Description Final   Adjustment  Adj Final
343     Visual        345            0    345
576     IO Tools    34543            0  34543
6567    Options      6356            0   6356
8675    Pickling     7456         5675  13131
345     Clipboard    5678            0   5678
6365    Flat         2355          645   3000
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from IPython.display import display, HTML

df = pd.DataFrame()

for filename in os.listdir('data1'):
    if filename.endswith(".xls"):
        print(f'appending {filename}')
        data = pd.read_excel(os.path.join("data1", filename), sheet_name=0)
        display(data)
        df.append(data)
        display(df)
    else:
        print(f'skipping {filename}, wrong data type')
```

The Output:

```
    appending a.xls
       Account  Description Final   Adjustment  Adj Final
    0      324     Testing1  2342            0       2342
    1      232    Essential  5678            0       5678
    2       35      Options  2345            0       2345
    3      634      Working    45         5675       5720
    4       23         Time 45774            0      45774
    5       52      Styling    67            0         67
    ___

    appending b.xls
       Account  Description Final   Adjustment  Adj Final
    0      343       Visual   345            0        345
    1      576     IO Tools 34543            0      34543
    2     6567      Options  6356            0       6356
    3     8675     Pickling  7456         5675      13131
    4      345    Clipboard  5678            0       5678
    5     6365         Flat  2355          645       3000
    ___
```

The `display(data)` produces the tables above, but the `display(df)` produces the `___`.  So, somehow I'm reading the excel file into `data`, but it isn't appending it to the `df`.

`df.info()` produces:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 0 entries
Empty DataFrame
```

My question is how to `append` the `data` into a single dataframe (`df`) for multiple excel workbooks.

Comment: The env is py3.6 in a Jupyter Notebook - hence the IPython.display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never reassign the variable `df`, then your dataframe is empty. You should do:

```
df = df.append(data)
```

Comment: Does that mean that every time you append it destroys the old object and a new one is created?

Comment: Well in that case yes. Sometimes with pandas, you have an `inplace` parameter that let you modify the current object but not for `append` apparently.

Comment: After understanding your answer I was able to find [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html).  In digging through the details it does note that **Append rows of other to the end of this frame, returning a new object**.  Thanks - everything working now.